# Trash Quick-Link removed - can get it back

Tags: pantheon-files

How can I reactivate the Trash Can on the left site of the Files window?

Answer (score 0):

It should not be possible to remove the Trash shortcut since a fix merged in February.  However, even if you have an older version and remove Trash, it should reappear on restarting Files.  The only exception is if you run as Administrator in which case there is no Trash support (anything deleted is deleted permanently).